# Stop code from copying header

Tags: vba

I have been tweaking the following vba code that copies data from a sheet into new sheets bases on a code in the column. My hang up is that I do not have headers so the code copies the first line to all the new sheets. How do I change the code so it does not look for a header?

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 5
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:AA1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
 ws.Range("A" & titlerow + 1 & ":A" & ...
```

This would skips the titlerow in the copy. (These things are hard to be sure of not having the sheet.)